# Will Modprobe automatically switch loadable kernel modules?

Tags: hybrid-graphics, vga, modprobe

I have hybrid graphics consists of nVIDIA GeForce graphics and Intel HD graphics. If I remove nVIDIA GeForce, can modprobe switch VGA lkm from nouveau to intel automatically on startup?

Comment: Not sure, but you could blacklist the nouveau graphics by putting it into /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Comment: It also means intel still on blacklist when I blaclist nouveau. How should I do to blacklist nouveau and get back the intel?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution  is to install [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html). It is a project aiming to provide switching between discreet and on-board cards on demand.

Comment: thank you, but I want to sell the discrette

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. Sorry, it has been along day and it's 00:59 local time... On your question, I remember a similar situation (alas on a desktop system) I had, where I removed a plug-in VGA and used the on-board one without any need for configuration, but I cannot guarantee that it was out of sheer luck or that something in the boot process detected the change. It was on a 12.04 lts 64bit system.

Comment: no problem, that's great experience, thank you.

if you have no important activities, you'd better get sleep soon.